# QString trouble in showing superscript

Tags: string, qt, qstring

I am having trouble showing superscript in Qt.

I am getting the string as std::string `IÂ²xt` . But, I have to show it as `I²xt` in QString.

I am getting the character Â as extra. How can I remove this character from the QString, and keep the superscript at the same time?

Comment: Do you have control over the source of the `std::string`?  It would be better to prevent the creation of the extra character rather than add a hack to remove it afterwards.

Comment: I don't have control over that :(. It's a third party API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use QString::fromUtf8(inputstring.c_str())